# how to reduce space between items in v-select component

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

```
 <v-select
          id="mySelect"
          v-model="filterEvents"
          :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '200' }"
          :items="eventsList"
          multiple
          class="pa-0 ma-0"
          height="5"
          width="10"
          outline
          autocomplete
          solo
          dense
          hide-details
          persistent-hint
        />
      </v-card>
```

i have two to three v-select in one page and want to reduced the space between items in v-select component and when we click on arrow button of v-select component the checkbox and item name not inline means some minor up-down in items name and checkbox ...i have also attached picture view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAStp.png)

Comment: The official way in adding dense prop as you already did it, other way you need to add css.

Comment: Ok ..then how to apply CSS for v-select ..because i have already apply ...but it doesn't work

Comment: v-select__selections input {
 padding: 0px;
}      i have applied this before